# Is it possible to modify Beamer presentation to create a loop only for a few slides of a presentation?

Tags: beamer

I have a Beamer presentation. I want few of the slide should run automatically on its own during the presentation unless I stop it. I already added `\transduration{0.75}` to show the next slide automatically, but I still need to figure out how to get back to a specific numbered slide and run the loop.